# jQuery custom content scroller doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have a [website](http://www.blackjackcafe.it/ferrarichallenge/facebook) where the  [jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller) doesn't work in Chrome.

As you can see, in the photo-list called "Lista Foto" and "Foto Album", I have an horizontal scroller under the photos.

But it works only in Firefox and not in Chrome.

Is there someone that could help me ?

Marco

[Edit] This is the script where I call the library:

```
(function($){
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#loader').fadeIn();
    $('#preloader').hide();
    $(".fotothumb,.fotothumb2").mCustomScrollbar({horizontalScroll: true});
});

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: It's normally expected that you post some code here for debugging. Post your plugin initialization function, at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the file .htaccess. The file now is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteRule ^ferrarichallenge/?$ ferrari.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^ferrarichallenge/facebook/?$ ferrarifacebook.php
RewriteRule ^ferrarichallenge/youtube/?$ ferrariyoutube.php [NC,L]


#<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
#Header set Expires "Wed, 15 Apr 2020 20:00:00 GMT"
#Header set Cache-Control "public"
#</FilesMatch>

#SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
#AddOutputFilter DEFLATE text/plain
#AddOutputFilter DEFLATE text/xml
#AddOutputFilter DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
#AddOutputFilter DEFLATE text/css
#AddOutputFilter DEFLATE application/xml
#AddOutputFilter DEFLATE image/svg+xml
#AddOutputFilter DEFLATE application/rss+xml
#AddOutputFilter DEFLATE application/atom_xml
#AddOutputFilter DEFLATE application/x-javascript
#AddOutputFilter DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
#AddOutputFilter DEFLATE application/x-httpd-fastphp
#AddOutputFilter DEFLATE application/x-httpd-eruby
#AddOutputFilter DEFLATE text/html
#SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
#SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|sit|rar)$ no-gzip dont-vary
#SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.pdf$ no-gzip dont-vary
#SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.avi$ no-gzip dont-vary
#SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.mov$ no-gzip dont-vary
#SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.mp3$ no-gzip dont-vary
#SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.mp4$ no-gzip dont-vary
#SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.rm$ no-gzip dont-vary
#BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
#BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
#BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
```

If I uncomment all the previous line the horizontal scrollbar is hide.

I haven't time to study the problem in depth but this is solve my question.